# Camunda Shared Engine Spring Junit factory-bean 'processEngine' returned null

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, camunda

I am writing a simple process application using Spring MVC and Camunda with a shared process engine. Now I want to add simple test cases and I am running into the problem that the process engine returns null for every factory method. When running the application the process engine returns the services as expected.

How should i configure camunda for JUnit tests, when using a shared process engine?

This is my camunda process engine configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- bind the process engine service as Spring Bean -->
<bean name="processEngineService" class="org.camunda.bpm.BpmPlatform" factory-method="getProcessEngineService" />

<!-- bind the default process engine as Spring Bean -->
<bean name="processEngine" factory-bean="processEngineService" factory-method="getDefaultProcessEngine" />

<bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService"/>
<bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService"/>
<bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService"/>
<bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService"/>
<bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService"/>
<bean id="identityService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getIdentityService"/>
<bean id="authorizationService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getAuthorizationService"/>

<!-- bootstrap the process application -->
<bean id="processApplication" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.application.SpringServletProcessApplication" />
</beans>
```

and this is the releavant part of my simple test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/process-conf.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hibernate-conf.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/camunda-conf.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml",
})
public class OrderControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        DefaultMockMvcBuilder builder = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac);
        this.mockMvc = builder.build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        ResultMatcher ok = MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk();
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/");
        this.mockMvc.perform(builder)
                .andExpect(ok);
    }
}
```

This is the exception that is thrown when starting the junit test:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryService' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/camunda-conf.xml]: factory-bean 'processEngine' (or a BeanPostProcessor involved) returned null
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in the debugger, and setting breakpoints in the factory methods?

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about running the debugger for camunda code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem via a workaround based on a guess:
It seems that the tests are rund directly in java, without the tomcat server instance. Therefore there is no shared process engine which can be accessed.

The solution:
I created another camunda configuration for an embedded process engine which uses the same database as the shared engine that is configured in the tomcat instance. The process engine can be instantiated then and the test is running fine. My guess is that one should be cautious to not have tomcat and the test run concurrently.

this is the embedded process engine configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CamundaProcessEngine_001?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="username" value="####"/>
        <property name="password" value="####"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <!-- turn off metrics reporter -->
        <property name="dbMetricsReporterActivate" value="false" />
        <property name="history" value="full" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processEngine" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService"/>
    <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService"/>
    <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService"/>
    <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService"/>
    <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService"/>
    <bean id="identityService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getIdentityService"/>
    <bean id="authorizationService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getAuthorizationService"/>

    <bean id="activitiRule" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.ProcessEngineRule">
        <property name="processEngine" ref="processEngine" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```